# integration of Joomla with existing application

Tags: api, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I want to integrate Joomla with one of existing applications. My application is also in PHP but I don't want to integrate at database level instead looking for API to access Joomla features like adding page etc. JFussion is available but its functionality is only limited to user functionality

Comment: I could have sworn you asked a question like this a couple of days ago. Again, you still need to provide more detail, research a few things, try something on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own component for Joomla!, create your own API in it to get parameters and output your desired data.

As far as I know there's no component to do that out-of-the-box and if there is it may not be suitable for your needs. Writing a customized component for your own needs is the best way and it's not that hard if you can understand basic concepts of Joomla! component-creating and object-oriented php programming.

That's what I did for my own component!

This may help: [Developing a Model-View-Controller Component for Joomla! 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5)